# Can't map to <C-i> in vim

Tags: vim, mapping

I just tried to map some command to CTRL + i, but it does not work and I don't get why.

Here is the desired mapping:

```
map <silent> <C-i> mmgg=G'm
```

When I map the command to e.g. F5 it works fine. So it has to do something with  but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, damn, just recognized that C-i generates the same character as TAB: [Look at this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-map-lt-tab-gt-and-lt-c-i-gt-independently-td1185417.html)

Comment: Damnit, I have to restart my vim because you now :P It overwrite supertab

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure why yours doesn't work, but this does:

```
map <silent> <C-i> :norm mmgg=G'm<CR>
```